# How can I get the table filter plugin to ignore the hash in the url?

Tags: jquery, hash, filter

I am using the [PicNet Table filter](http://www.picnet.com.au/picnet-table-filter.html) for filtering data in a table. It's working very well. A problem I've encountered however is that it's conflicting with my internal tab navigation. The tab navigation (jQuery UI) uses e.g. www.url.com#1 or www.url.com#2 to navigate between tabs. The table filter on page #2 picks up this and adds 2 to the input field of the filter.

I have tried a lot of trickery to clear it, but I haven't found a feasible solution. Is there a way I can modify the script to ignore the hashes altogether, or make the hash invisible for it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the function running before the filtering happens (filteringRows), and checking for the hash value from the url, if it was the culprit I just removed it and made a standard text as the value for the text field until the user clicks it to enter his own values.